# AWS CloudFormation: Cognito LambdaTrigger CustomEmailSender - Property "Not currently supported by AWS CloudFormation." and CDK usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

Generally what means Property "Not currently supported by AWS CloudFormation" for a CDK implementation, specifically:

In the CloudFormation Properties for the Cognito Userpool Lambda Config it says:
CustomEmailSender - Not currently supported by AWS CloudFormation.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-lambdaconfig.html

In the CDK for Cognito.CfnUssrPool this property is described:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cognito.CfnUserPool.LambdaConfigProperty.html#customemailsender

My question now is whether this can be implemented with CDK at all? Currently, our Cognito is provided completely via CDK and I would like to keep it that way.

---

Edit:

I found a link ([Using CustomEmailSender with CFN](https://www.maxivanov.io/send-aws-cognito-emails-with-3rd-party-esps/)) where it says that contrary to the documentation it does seem to work and only the documentation has not been updated, I will test this and give feedback.

Comment: CDK boils down to a CloudFormation template, if CloudFormation does not support a property then CDK cannot use it either. If you do not need the property you are fine - if you need it then you have a problem.

Comment: @luk2302 thanks for your comment, do you know why it is descripted in the CDK docs? Do you have any idea for a workaround?

Comment: The workaround is to not use CDK / CloudFormation :D and I do not understand the first question, the CDK docs is basically a copy of the cloudformation docs in terms of property and feature documentation.

Comment: @luk2302 ok, so do you know any other way to setup Cognito by Infrastructure-as-a-code, I want to prevent manually steps for the configuration. And to clarify my "1st question", why AWS add a property to the CDK docs if it isn't usable, but see this as a rhetorical question ;)

Comment: You can always set up and use custom resources in CloudFormation. The alternative would be to use another IaC tool like terraform but that is a major change / shift.

Comment: I was afraid of that, thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing CustomEmailSender CDK implementation, I have to say that the AWS CloudFormation Documentation hasn't a current state. So it is possible to use this function by CFN and CDK. [AWS Doc CFN Cognito CustomEmailSender](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html)

ToDos in CDK:

- Configure Cognito: instead of using the property `emailConfiguration` you have to use `lambdaConfig`:

```
lambdaConfig: {
        customEmailSender: { lambdaArn: customSenderEmailLambdaArn, lambdaVersion: 'V1_0' }, 
        // the version is an ENUM so be careful when you set it
        kmsKeyId: kmsKeyArn,
      },
```

- As you see here you have also to set up a KMS Key (you can adjust an existing one or create a new KMS key). The most important thing here is that you allow the action `kms:CreateGrant` to Cognito AND the Lambda function!
- Another important ToDo is to add your Lambda the permission for Cognito, action `cognito-idp:InvokeFunction`.
- The big advantage of using CustomEmailSender instead of the common Lambda Triggers that you don't have to set all the triggers in you CDK code or in the Cognito Console (all email events will be sent automatically to your lambda).